# Can I use a content resolver in my application without creating a provider?

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

I am reading the developer guide about the content providers and as it's mentioned there that I shouldn't create my own provider unless there is a need to.

So my questions are:

- Can I use content resolver in my application without creating my own provider?
- What is the best approach? should I use always a content resolver (and create my own provider if necessary) to do all the operations with the DB or talking to SQLiteHelper class directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can I use content resolver in my application without creating my own provider?

You can use a `ContentResolver` with any other existing `ContentProvider`, such as those supplied by the OS (e.g., `ContactsContract`).

> should I use always a content resolver (and create my own provider if necessary) to do all the operations with the DB or talking to SQLiteHelper class directly

There are differing opinions on that subject. Personally, I am not a big fan of `ContentProvider`, and so I only use it when I need to, such as for inter-process communication. However, there are those who think that using `ContentProvider` purely for internal use within an app is wonderful. There is no right or wrong answer.